# php pdo class cannot run execute

Tags: php, class, object, pdo, execute

I am trying to create a PDO class and I get the error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object on line 39

to call this class I create a new database object that connects with no problems then I do this:

```
$newDailyTotal = array(
    array('date',time()),
    array('cash',300)
);

$db->insert('dailyTotals',$newDailyTotal);
```

it echos out INSERT INTO dailyTotals(date,cash) values (?,?)

so that seems fine too.
thanks for all the help.

```
<?
```

class Database {

```
private $DBH;


//connects to the database
function __construct($host,$dbname,$user,$pass) {    
    try {  
        $this->DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  
        $this->DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
    }  
        catch(PDOException $e) {  
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }
}

//inserts into the database
//$tableName name of the table to insert the info into
//$items is a multidimensional array of array(column name, value)
public function insert($tableName,$items){
    $values = array();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName(";
    $valuePlaceHolder = ''; // holds the question marks at the end of the PDO sql string

    foreach($items as $item){
        $sql .= $item[0] . ',';
        array_push($values, $item[1]);
        $valuePlaceHolder .= '?,';
    }

    // remove the last comma from the sql statement
    $sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
    $valuePlaceHolder  = substr($valuePlaceHolder, 0, -1);

    $sql .= ") values ($valuePlaceHolder)";
    echo $sql;

    $SHT = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
    $STH->execute($values); 
}
```

}

?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $SHT = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
   $STH->execute($values);
```

Variables are spelled differently.... long day? ;-)

Comment: Heh.. yes, yes I have. I was struggling over that far more than any programmer ever should...

Answer (score 0):

`date` is a reserved word, you'll need to add backticks to it

```
INSERT INTO dailyTotals(date,cash) values (?,?)
```

to

```
INSERT INTO dailyTotals(`date`,`cash`) values (?,?)
```

You'll need to change your `sql .= ...` in your loop to

```
$sql .= '`' . $item[0] . '`,';
```